# Binding does't work in release mod

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin, binding

I created a Xamarin Android App and it works perfectly in debug mode, but when I tried to run it in release mode the Xaml binding doesn't work.

I also had a event handler for a searchBar, but I've deleted it because the application doesn't start. It crashes at start and throws this error: `No method SearchBar_OnTextChanged found`.

Also in Xaml at the name of the list I get this error: "Field SymbolList is already declared" and in the code behind when I use the SymbolList name I get:  "Ambiguous References".

What could cause this behavior?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ElectricalSymbols"
             x:Class="ElectricalSymbols.MainPage"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False">

    <StackLayout>
        <SearchBar Placeholder="Search..." TextChanged="SearchBar_OnTextChanged"/>
        <ListView x:Name="SymbolList" 
                  IsGroupingEnabled="true"
                  GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding Family}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ImageCell ImageSource="{Binding Image}" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Did you try a clean and rebuild whilst in release mode? Also a common one is to check what the 'linker' settings are for debug and release, see if there is a difference

Comment: Is the `Linker` turned on your release mode build?